# How to use grep on files in python

Tags: python, debian

I am trying to do make a script that will show users in a group the problem is I don't know how to properly use grep in python. My code goes something like this:

```
with open("/etc/group" , "r") as f2:
  for line in f2:
    grouplist=line.split(":")
    print grouplist[0]

group_choose = raw_input("Choose a group > ")
glist = "1)show users in group \n2)Show group ID \n3)Add user to the group
print
print glist
print
```

I want the "Show users in the group" script to be similar to the one I just did with opening the file and doing a grep to filter only the users in the group that will be mentioned in"group_choose". I would also love to hear an explanation on how you did it since I don't really know how to use grep in python.

Comment: can you show the file /etc/group in your post.  It looks like the user are in grouplist[3] separated by a comma if more than one user

Comment: The group folder looks like this:

    root:x:0:
    daemon:x:1:
    bin:x:2:
and if there is a member in the group it shows like this:

    audio:x:29:pulse,nik
    scanner:x:115:saned,nik

each group is in a separate line, for some reason it won't let me make a new line.

Answer (score 1):

My take on this would be to read the content of "/etc/group" and create a key/value list based on the groupe name.

Very crude example (with harcoded values, since I don't have access to a "/etc/group" file) :

```
line="G1:X:T2:u1,u2,u3"
groups=[]
users=line.split(":")[3].split(",")
groupname=line.split(":")[0]
groups.append([groupname,users])

for group in groups:
 if group[0]=="G1":
   print group[1]
```